# find element nth position within parent

Tags: jquery

If I have this:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#"></a>a</li>
    <li><a href="#"></a>b</li>
    <li><a href="#"></a>c</li>
    <li><a href="#"></a>d</li>
    <li><a href="#"></a>e</li>
</ul>
```

And lets say I clicked on third li item (with a content of 'c').
How Could I get the info this item is third within 'ul' parent?

Comment: [`$(this).index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/)

Comment: BTW, Your markup is wrong because you don't properly close your `<a>` tags in the first and last `<li>`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
$('li').click(
    function () {
        alert($(this).index());
    });
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/KyTP5/

Note that this gives you the *zero-based* index.